# Watson IBM Speech to Text c# api

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I using follow example to recognize text from audio https://gist.github.com/nfriedly/0240e862901474a9447a600e5795d500 but I need also time codes, i added at line 40  `"timestamps" : true`, and removed  `"interim_results": true` as I need only final results. But it broken, after `{ "state": "listening" }` message it takes some time and raise exception like that
`"Text" received message is invalid after the call Websocket.Closeasync. Websockets.In cases closeasync, so you should only use those when you do not expect to receive other data from the remote endpoint. Use "Websockets.CloseOutputAsync" to preserve the possibility of obtaining additional data, but to close the outgoing channel.`

And if i set  `"continuous" : false`, It do only the first iteration of speech (few first words before a pause), and then repeat `{"state": "listening" }` and freezes.

Can you help me, how to update that example to return Timecodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`continuous: false` means "only transcribe until the first pause" - so it isn't "freezing", it's just stopping when you tell it to.

The service then sends the final results followed by the second `{"state": "listening"}` message to indicate that it's done sending results. The example code closes the connection after that, but it sound like you're still attempting to send audio after closing the connection.

I'm not certain, but I think that `timestamps` and `interim_results` will probably work the way you want once you set `continuous: false`.

Although, if you only need final results, then the HTTP interface might make more sense. It's much simpler than the WebSockets one.

Finally, as I mentioned in email, the official IBM Watson .net SDK has support for Speech to Text in the [development branch](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk) right now, and should have it included in [a release](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud/) soon.

Comment: Thanx for response, I saw you email. Official sdk is for .net core, which i not familiar, and not sure if its possible to use in one project core libs and 'old .net' libs. I used python example, and run that from my c# app, and after that generated json, using that back at c# :)